# How to provide default data in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have recently integrated Cloud Firestore into my app and it works fine so far.
I noticed, that if user install and launch the app for the first time, there is no data inside the Firestore, as long as there is no internet connection provided. Is it able to deliver some kind of base dataset to the user (e.g. a copy of the database at a specific time), because the data doesn't change very frequently?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the user has no internet connection, then there is no way to deliver any data to the user that isn't hardcoded into the client. I'm guessing this isn't what you're asking, so try re-wording your question. What do you mean by `there is no data inside the firestore` and `as long as there is no internet connection provided`?

Comment: @WillB yes indeed. What i thought about was to provide a kind of base dataset (kind of hard coded), like e.g. a copy of the firebase firestore AT compile-time. After the first sync (going online) the user could have a updated version of the database. Is that even possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user starts the app for the first time and if there is no internet connection on user's device, there is and there will be **no way** so you can get some data from Firebase servers. If you want to have some data in your application till the user gets connected to the internet, then you should prepopulate your views with some data. So you can manually create some data and if the user starts the app with no internet connection, show that data to the the user. When the user regains connection, then show the data that it comes from Firebase servers.

But note, the data that you have added manually, should be displayed to the user only **once** because once the user is connected to Firebase server and the user has the `offline persistens enabled` (which by default is enabled), it means that the user will be able to query the database even if he is offline. This is happening because Firebase creates a local copy of the database that will persist even after the app/device restarts. Every change that is made while he is offline, will be updated on Firebase servers once he is back online.

Comment: Okay, so there is no way to kind of mirror the actual database at compile time and use that as 'temporary source' for initial use? Else i would have to populate some default data, indeed. Does firebase sync the data, even if i never started the app (network connection available)?

Comment: 1. No, there is not. Since there is no internet connection, you cannot get any data from the Firebase servers. 2. Yes, you should populate with some default data till the user gets connected to the internet. 3. No, even if you have the network connection available, you should open the app, so Firebase can open a connection to the servers. Without opening a connection to the server, with other words, without instantiating a `FirebaseFirestore` object using its static method `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()`, you cannot get any data from the servers.

Comment: That's all i needed to know. Thanks.